# MS-DOS Batch: Non-Recursive File Searching in a Directory

Tags: search, batch-file

My goal is to search in ANY directory in the C:\ drive--but not the directories of those directories--for a file named "setup95.exe". If the file exists, then I need to write the path to a variable called `%getpath%`.

I was originally trying to simply use `dir` but it doesn't meet my expectations. I need to get ANY directory in C:\ and search through it. As an exemplar, say I there is a folder in C:\ called `__neverhood`. Within that folder, there is a file named `setup95.exe`. The program doesn't know what folder it is it. It only knows it is in C:\, so it needs to search through each directory in C:\ to find `setup95.exe`.

UPDATE: New code. It finds the file, but it's no good for the disk drive. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "traversity=C:\Program Files (x86)\"
if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)" SET "traversity=C:\Program Files\"

SET intricacy=%traversity%The Neverhood Restoration Project
SET obscurity=%traversity%DreamWorks Interactive
SET psychedelia=%obscurity%\Neverhood
SET abstraction=WAVistaWin7.exe

:removenrp
if exist "%traversity%The Neverhood Restoration Project Julia\unins000.exe" ( 
    "%traversity%The Neverhood Restoration Project Julia\unins000.exe"
)

:delreg
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 ( 
    reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DreamWorks Interactive" /f
) else ( 
    if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 ( 
        reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DreamWorks Interactive" /f
    ) else (
        reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DreamWorks Interactive" /f
)) 

if exist "%obscurity%" echo y | rmdir /S /Q "%obscurity%"


mkdir "%obscurity%"
mkdir "%psychedelia%"
copy /Y "%~dp0%abstraction%" "%psychedelia%"
for /d %%a in (c:\*) do for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "%%~a\setup95.exe" 2^>nul') do set "getpath=%%~a"
if defined getpath (echo path is %getpath%) else rem ok 

if exist "%getpath%setup95.exe" (
    echo MSGBOX "Pyroneous did not distribute the Neverhood illicitly to you. Remember that the only legal way to run the Neverhood is to buy it. We will still permit you to install the Neverhood, but we are not responsible for your actions. You can read our full purposes at theneverhood.sourceforge.net. Thanks!" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
    call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
    del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
    reg import "%~dp0neverhood.reg"
    START "%getpath%setup95.exe"
) else (
    for %%D in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do vol %%D: >output 2>output && if exist %%D:\setup95.exe set DRIVE=%%D
    if not defined DRIVE echo It appears you don't have the Neverhood on your computer. Please check http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/setup/ for more information. && pause
    if exist "%DRIVE%:\setup95.exe" (
        echo MSGBOX "Hey. Thank you for purchasing the Neverhood. That is, if you're not using an burned ISO/exploitation." > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
        call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
        del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
        reg import "%~dp0neverhood.reg"
        START D:\setup95.exe
```

)
)

The output returns this:

```
C:\Users\b\Desktop\somnacea\files\thankyousanta\necessity>install.bat
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
        1 file(s) copied.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
It appears you don't have the Neverhood on your computer. Please check http://th
eneverhood.sourceforge.net/setup/ for more information.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your question is as clear as mud. An example would have been good.

Are you asking how to detect whether the said file exists in a directory that you nominate, or whether any particular file exists?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: version 1 - if you want to specify the drive and path and file
FOR /f %%i IN ("%~1") DO IF EXIST "%%i" (SET getpath=%%~pi) ELSE (SET getpath=)
ECHO (1) getpath=%getpath%

:: version 2 - if you want to specify path and assume drive and file
FOR /f %%i IN ("c:\%~1\setup95.exe") DO IF EXIST "%%i" (SET getpath=%%~pi) ELSE (SET getpath=)
ECHO (2) getpath=%getpath%
```

Running this with a parameter of `"c:\directory I\want to\find\setup95.exe"` should work with the first version (`getpath` set to the path if the file exists, empty otherwise)

Running this with a parameter of `"\directory I\want to\find"` should work with the second version (`getpath` set to the path if the file exists, empty otherwise)

But - if you already know what your path is, why don't you simply use `if exist "c:\path I want\to know\about\setup95.exe"` ?

And if you don't know, what do you mean by `"ANY directory in the C:\ drive--but not the directories of those directories"` ?

---

given  more data:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "getpath="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d c:\setup95.exe'
  ) DO IF DEFINED getpath (ECHO also found IN %%~pi) ELSE (SET getpath=%%~pi)
IF DEFINED getpath (ECHO first found AT %getpath%) ELSE (ECHO NOT found)
```

should show first place found, whether found in more places or whether found at all.